# SortedVector not calling functions properly?

Tags: c++, function, class, vector

The compiler is telling me that these functions do not belong to my class or vector. I'm a bit confused as to where I could have gone wrong. Any help would be appreciated as i scramble to figure this out. I put the header for vector but that does not resolve the issue. It seems as though my compiler is failing to detect my .h file and my private variable sorted_vector.

//Compiler

```
In file included from SortedVector.cpp:1:0:
SortedVector.h:22:3: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
   vector<int> sorted_vector;
   ^~~~~~
SortedVector.cpp: In constructor ‘SortedVector::SortedVector(int)’:
SortedVector.cpp:5:2: error: ‘sorted_vector’ was not declared in this scope
  sorted_vector.reserve(cap);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
SortedVector.cpp: In member function ‘int SortedVector::getCapacity() const’:
SortedVector.cpp:9:9: error: ‘sorted_vector’ was not declared in this scope
  return sorted_vector.capacity();
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
SortedVector.cpp: In member function ‘int SortedVector::getSize() const’:
SortedVector.cpp:13:9: error: ‘sorted_vector’ was not declared in this scope
  return sorted_vector.size();
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
SortedVector.cpp: In member function ‘bool SortedVector::isEmpty() const’:
SortedVector.cpp:17:6: error: ‘sorted_vector’ was not declared in this scope
  if (sorted_vector.empty())
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
SortedVector.cpp: In member function ‘void SortedVector::insertVal(int)’:
SortedVector.cpp:25:8: error: ‘sorted_vector’ was not declared in this scope
     if(sorted_vector.isEmpty())
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
SortedVector.cpp:28:8: error: ‘sorted_vector’ was not declared in this scope
     if(sorted_vector.isEmpty()){
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
SortedVector.cpp: At global scope:
SortedVector.cpp:39:5: error: prototype for ‘int SortedVector::find(int)’ does not match any in class ‘SortedVector’
 int SortedVector::find(int val) {
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from SortedVector.cpp:1:0:
SortedVector.h:14:7: error: candidate is: int SortedVector::find(int) const
   int find(int val) const;
       ^~~~
SortedVector.cpp: In member function ‘bool SortedVector::deleteVal(int)’:
SortedVector.cpp:50:2: error: ‘vector’ was not declared in this scope
  vector<int> temp;
  ^~~~~~
SortedVector.cpp:50:2: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/vector:64:0,
                 from SortedVector.h:6,
                 from SortedVector.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:214:11: note:   ‘std::vector’
     class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
           ^~~~~~
SortedVector.cpp:50:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
  vector<int> temp;
         ^~~
SortedVector.cpp:51:2: error: ‘temp’ was not declared in this scope
  temp.reserve(sorted_vector.capacity());
  ^~~~
SortedVector.cpp:51:15: error: ‘sorted_vector’ was not declared in this scope
  temp.reserve(sorted_vector.capacity());
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
SortedVector.cpp:75:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 }
```

//SortedVector.h

```
#ifndef SORTEDVECTOR_H_
#define SORTEDVECTOR_H_

#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;
#include <vector>

class SortedVector {

    public:
        SortedVector();
        SortedVector(int cap = 10);
        void insertVal(int val);
        int find(int val) const;
        bool deleteVal(int val);
        bool isEmpty() const;
        friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const SortedVector & sV);
        int getCapacity() const;
        int getSize() const;

    private:
        vector<int> sorted_vector;

};

#endif
```

//SortedVector.cpp

```
#include "SortedVector.h"
#include <vector>

SortedVector::SortedVector(int cap) {
    sorted_vector.reserve(cap);
}

int SortedVector::getCapacity() const{
    return sorted_vector.capacity();
    }

int SortedVector::getSize() const{
    return sorted_vector.size();
}

bool SortedVector::isEmpty() const{
    if (sorted_vector.empty())
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}

void SortedVector::insertVal(int val) {
    if(sorted_vector.isEmpty())
        sorted_vector.push_back(val);

    if(sorted_vector.isEmpty()){
        for(int i=0;i!=sorted_vector.size();i++){
            if(sorted_vector[i]<=val)
                sorted_vector.insertVal(val);

        }
    }
}



int SortedVector::find(int val) {
    for(int i=0; i<sorted_vector.size(); i++){
        if(sorted_vector[i]==val)
            return i;
        else
            return -1;

    }
}

bool SortedVector::deleteVal(int val) {
    vector<int> temp;
    temp.reserve(sorted_vector.capacity());
    temp = sorted_vector;
    int idx = sorted_vector.find(val)
    if (idx!= -1 ){
        for(int i =0; i<sorted_vector.size(); i++){
            if(i==idx)
                continue;
            temp.push_back(sorted_vector[i]);
        }
        sorted_vector=temp;
        return true
    }
    else
        return false;

}


ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const SortedVector & sV) {
    for(int i = 0; i < sV.getSize(); i++) {
        out << sV.sorted_vector[i] << " ";
    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: The compiler is telling you it doesn't know what `vector` is. What is `vector`? Do you mean `std::vector`?

Comment: When you have a cascade of errors, usually the later ones are caused by the earlier ones preventing things from compiling. Only focus on the top error. @Tas gives you the answer you seek.

Comment: And don't you dare `using namespace std;` in a header file!!! Prepend `std::` to `vector` like suggested .

Comment: do i also #include<vector>?

Comment: Yes, add a #include in every file that you use anything from it.

Comment: >do i also #include<vector>?
You defenitely sould!  
Replace vector<int>  by std::vector<int> because vector<> template is defined in std namespace.

Comment: @JohnFilleau actually OP does not do `using namespace std;` at least with shown code

Comment: @slava agreed. There's two solutions to OP's problem though - prepend `std::` or `using namespace std;`. We can all agree that the latter is not a good solution because of the headaches it will cause whenever someone includes this file. I just wanted to make sure they didn't try using the path of darkness.